How do Web and Entangle interact?
Our party had some bad guys that were trying to run away through some brush. The wizard cast Web and three failed their save. The druid cast Entangle in the same space and all three failed their save.
Not counting the initial save when the web appears (correction per answer -- initial save occurs at the start of the creature's turn after the web appears), the Web spell has two key components (please note I'm refering to the legacy 2014 version):

A creature restrained by the webs can use its action to make a Strength check against your spell save DC. If it succeeds, it is no longer restrained.
Each creature that starts its turn in the webs or that enters them during its turn must make a Dexterity saving throw. On a failed save, the creature is restrained as long as it remains in the webs or until it breaks free.

The Entangle spell includes the following text:

A creature in the area when you cast the spell must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be restrained by the entangling plants until the spell ends. A creature restrained by the plants can use its action to make a Strength check against your spell save DC. On a success, it frees itself.

Based on my reading of this question, it seems the creatures caught by both spells need at least two actions and two saving throws (correction per answer -- successful STR checks) to break free -- one against the entangle and one against the web. A smart creature will, if possible, break the Entangle first; if the creature foolishly chooses to break the Web first, then the creature must save against Web on the next turn while they're trying to free themselves from the Entangle.
Questions:

Is my understanding of how Web and Entangle interact correct?
How much agency does the mob have in choosing which spell to save against? I'm guessing this is a "the rules don't cover it, so the affected creature gets to pick and/or choose the order" situation.
How smart does the creature need to be to choose Entangle first? I understand the answer is likely to be "it's up to your game master", but are there any rules that would provide guidelines?


Hi user76491.  While you naturally want to have your question be accurate and the best reflection of what you are asking, please note that we generally don't encourage edits that invalidate existing answers.  (Cf. here).  Both answers to this question point out that you made a mistake in assuming web gets an initial save on casting (and one linked to a similar question) and another mistake in saying that the restrained condition could be broken by saves (but not checks).

By fixing those mistakes, your question looks better, both both existing answers now look worse, as it appears to a new reader that they are addressing points you did not make.  A new answer could come in and address your new, revised question and appear better than the answers that took the time to correct your misconceptions.  Please consider rolling back those edits.

Thanks for the guidance. I'll modify the edit to point out the correction due to an answer. Does this thread the needle of making the question more accurate without invalidating answers?

Your new edits are a good balance between asking what you want to know and respecting the answers that already came in.  Well done.

The saves are made at different times, and are not chosen
There is a fundamental difference in the timing of the saves against the two spells.  As your quotes actually show, the save against Entangle is made at the time the spell is cast, typically on the turn of the caster.  The save against web, however, is made at the start of the turn of the target.
Since it is unlikely that the two saves will be made at the same time, a target typically would not face a choice of which save to attempt first.
A further difference between the spells is that if the save is successful against Entangle, the creature is then immune to the restraining effect of the spell for the rest of its duration - it is "one and done".  Web, on the other hand, will provoke a new save on any turn a target starts in its area of effect or enters it.  Web is a "gift that keeps on giving".
You do have some misunderstandings of the spells.  You say "Not counting the initial save when the web appears" - but there is no initial save when the web appears (unlike most AoE spells).  Instead, there is a save at the start of the turn of each target.  This creates a sort of Schrödinger's web effect - after the spell is cast, we do not actually know whether the targets are restrained or not until the start of their turn.  This uncertainty can produce strange effects.
Further, you say: "the creatures caught by both spells need at least two actions and two successful saving throws to break free".  If by "caught" you mean the initial saving throws were failed (the entangle on the caster's turn and the web on the target's turn), then a target could be freed by a minimum of two actions and two successful checks (but not saves).
The checks are made at the same time, and there is a choice
A creature who is currently restrained by both spells can make a Str check for each to break free, but this requires an action for each check.  Since most creatures will have only a single action on their turn, they would need to choose one check or the other.
The smart choice is entangle first, because just like for the save, a single successful check permanently removes the restraining effect of the spell.  A creature who unwisely chose to use its action to break free of web but which was still restrained by entangle would be unable to move, and would thus start its next turn in the webs, triggering another saving throw that could easily result in it being restrained by the webs again - and thus having wasted its action on its previous turn to have achieved nothing, despite the successful prior check.
How do you describe the choice?
How smart an NPC has to be to choose entangle first depends on the nature of your world, and how aware, or unaware, creatures are of the underlying mechanics.  I like Dale M's summary of different views - either the characters themselves are aware of the mechanics and can make choices based on that, or the players are aware of the mechanics, which are just a proxy for the reasonable in-world decisions the characters are making, or the players don't have to be aware of anything - they are just making decisions for what the characters are trying to do and the DM is applying mechanics on the fly to represent those choices.
In this particular case, the third approach makes the most sense to me, based on the descriptions of the spells.  Because a single save or check is enough to escape entangle, but webs are a continual menace, that informs my narrative description of them.  For me, the entangle spell creates grasping vines, but once you have ripped free of the vines they remain broken and are no longer a threat.  The sticky webs, on the other hand, continually pull at you (or collapse onto you, since they are five feet deep!), so breaking any particular strands on this turn does not help you next turn.  Envisioning the spells like this, narratively you would have to make the entangle check first - until you have ripped free of the vines, you can't begin to deal with the sticky webs pulling at you, but breaking free of the webs on any given round will do nothing to the vines.  Thus there is no choice a character has to make, and the order is simply a consequence of the nature of the spells.

The issue with "use a narrative" as an answer is that it's easy to change the narrative: I need only assume that the vines bind your feet because you're still standing, so until you remove the Web from your upper body, you'll have difficulty removing vines from your feet. I really don't see any text that would support one narrative over the other.

@user76491 I was suggesting the narrative approach as what I would do to resolve this situation, not as RAW.  I can edit if you think that is unclear.

Excellent parsing of two of my favorite spells that have significant mechanical differences!

Answering your three questions at the question body, with question 2 and 3 rephrased to be shorter:
1. Is my understanding of how Web and Entangle interact correct?
Yes, you described the interaction between Entangle and Web perfectly. Just note that the action you do to break free is a check not a save, as also noted by Kirt in their answer. And that there is no initial save in Web. (but these are not about the interactions)
2. How much agency a creature have in choosing which to break first?
The spells are independent, so the creature has all agency to choose which one to break free first. This is covered in the general rules about Action:

When you take your action on your turn, you can take one of the actions presented here, an action you gained from your class or a special feature, or an action that you improvise. Many monsters have action options of their own in their stat blocks.

Being restrained simply gives you more options on what you can do with your Action. You still need to choose.
3. How to determine whether a creature would choose Entangle first?
This varies on the creature's behavior (e.g., a spider creature probably would try to break free of the Entangle first, being more comfortable with webbing), but I'd rule at least a creature that knows the Entangle/Web spell or has interacted with the spell before would know that the Entangle spell is a once and done thing while Web isn't, and any smart creature given that knowledge would do the wise thing to do, which is to break Entangle first.
If you want to codify this, probably can use the fact that 10 Intelligence is considered average (Commoner), which I assume would perfectly understand to break Entangle first. You can also compare with other monsters and compare the Int scores. Giant Ape has 7 Int, and probably smart enough to figure this out. So probably at least 7 Int is a good starting point.
